# I use Ubuntu 16:04; why is the boot process so long? 17 minutes

Tags: boot, 16.04, plymouth, apparmor

[image]

How do I fix the problem of slow boot on my laptop?

```
17min 22.499s apparmor.service 
17min 20.846s plymouth-start.service 
17min 19.516s plymouth-read-write.service 
46.252s apt-daily.service 
35.582s lightdm.service 
32.776s plymouth-quit-wait.service 
10.969s ModemManager.service 
9.437s dev-sda5.device 
9.090s accounts-daemon.service 
6.472s preload.service 
6.420s grub-common.service 
5.680s speech-dispatcher.service 
5.655s NetworkManager.service 
5.556s systemd-logind.service 
5.475s ondemand.service
```

Comment: You should post terminal output as plain text (code formatted) instead of screenshots for better usability.

Comment: 17min 22.499s apparmor.service
   17min 20.846s plymouth-start.service
   17min 19.516s plymouth-read-write.service
         46.252s apt-daily.service
         35.582s lightdm.service
         32.776s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         10.969s ModemManager.service
          9.437s dev-sda5.device
          9.090s accounts-daemon.service
          6.472s preload.service
          6.420s grub-common.service
          5.680s speech-dispatcher.service
          5.655s NetworkManager.service
          5.556s systemd-logind.service
          5.475s ondemand.service

Comment: I meant you should [edit] your question to add it.

Answer (score 2):

A [similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854342/long-bootign-on-ubuntu-16-04) blaming apparmor and plymouth turned out to be caused by a swap partition on a slow disk.

```
swapon
```

will tell you which partition and disk you are currently using and how much of it is in use.

You can test if using a swapfile on your main hard disk speeds up the boot sequence. 4 GB is a reasonable swap file size for a modern desktop computer, but make sure your computer has 4 GB available on its root partition:

```
df -h /
```

shows you how much space you have available under *Avail*. If it is less than 4 GB, adjust the size below to the space you have available. Create the swapfile and use it as swap:

```
sudo fallocate --length 4GB /swapfile
sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Finally, edit /etc/fstab to ensure that /swapfile is used for swap after you reboot.

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Add the following line to declare that /swapfile should be used for swap next time you reboot:

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw    0   0
```

Now reboot and see if it is still slow.